# why the checkpoint go wrong when the model is running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t70Bf.png)
I post a image here
excues me,when i use callbacks=[checkpoint] to fit,erro occured so the problem is path or other parameters in checkpoint ?

> OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 7                     shuffle=True,
> 8                     callbacks=[checkpoint], #earlystop],
> ----> 9                     validation_split=0.1)
> 10                     #validation_data=(x_test, y_test), reduce_lr
> 11  g:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
> validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
> sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
> validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing,
> **kwargs)    1237                                         steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,    1238
> validation_steps=validation_steps,
> -> 1239                                         validation_freq=validation_freq)    1240     1241     def
> evaluate(self,
> g:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py
> in fit_loop(model, fit_function, fit_inputs, out_labels, batch_size,
> epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_function, val_inputs, shuffle,
> initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq)
> 214                         epoch_logs['val_' + l] = o
> 215
> --> 216         callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
> 217         if callbacks.model.stop_training:
> 218             break g:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks\callbacks.py in
> on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
> 150         logs = logs or {}
> 151         for callback in self.callbacks:
> --> 152             callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
> 153
> 154     def on_train_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None): g:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks\callbacks.py in
> on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
> 728                     self.model.save_weights(filepath, overwrite=True)
> 729                 else:
> --> 730                     self.model.save(filepath, overwrite=True)
> 731
> 732  g:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py in save(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)    1150
> raise NotImplementedError    1151         from ..models import
> save_model
> -> 1152         save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)    1153     1154     @saving.allow_write_to_gcs
> g:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py in
> save_wrapper(obj, filepath, overwrite, *args, **kwargs)
> 447                 os.remove(tmp_filepath)
> 448         else:
> --> 449             save_function(obj, filepath, overwrite, *args, **kwargs)
> 450
> 451     return save_wrapper g:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py in
> save_model(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
> 538             if not proceed:
> 539                 return
> --> 540         with H5Dict(filepath, mode='w') as h5dict:
> 541             _serialize_model(model, h5dict, include_optimizer)
> 542     elif hasattr(filepath, 'write') and callable(filepath.write):
> g:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\io_utils.py in
> **init**(self, path, mode)
> 189             self._is_file = False
> 190         elif isinstance(path, six.string_types) or _is_path_instance(path):
> --> 191             self.data = h5py.File(path, mode=mode)
> 192             self._is_file = True
> 193         elif isinstance(path, dict): g:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\h5py_hl\files.py in
> **init**(self, name, mode, driver, libver, userblock_size, swmr, rdcc_nslots, rdcc_nbytes, rdcc_w0, track_order, **kwds)
> 406                 fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size,
> 407                                fapl, fcpl=make_fcpl(track_order=track_order),
> --> 408                                swmr=swmr)
> 409
> 410             if isinstance(libver, tuple): g:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\h5py_hl\files.py in
> make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr)
> 177         fid = h5f.create(name, h5f.ACC_EXCL, fapl=fapl, fcpl=fcpl)
> 178     elif mode == 'w':
> --> 179         fid = h5f.create(name, h5f.ACC_TRUNC, fapl=fapl, fcpl=fcpl)
> 180     elif mode == 'a':
> 181         # Open in append mode (read/write). h5py_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper() h5py_objects.pyx in
> h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper() h5py\h5f.pyx in h5py.h5f.create()
> OSError:

```
 model = Sequential()
 model.add(LSTM(30, input_shape=(time_step,attr), dropout=0.2, return_sequences=False,kernel_regularizer=l1_l2(0.05,0.05),activity_regularizer=l1_l2(0.04,0.07)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('double_tanh'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer= 'rmsprop', metrics=['mae', 'mse'])

save_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'models')

filepath="model_{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5" 

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join(save_dir, filepath), monitor='val_loss',
                             verbose=1, save_weights_only=False, save_best_only=False, mode='min',period=1)

history = model.fit(_train_X, _train_Y, batch_size=32, epochs=160, 
                    shuffle=True,
                    callbacks=[checkpoint], #earlystop],
                    validation_split=0.1)
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing the data and the code that you have written that produces your problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Comment: @itprorh66 thanks for reply.Would  you please tell me the code and the data that you need to debug?

Comment: @rose-25 Please format your traceback better (using the code snippet format). Looks like some parts are also missing (the actual error message instead of only OSError)

Comment: The following three references give excellent advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)

Comment: also, posting an image of your code is not  helpful, See [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: This might not be the answer but your filepath variable has to be an f string I believe for the values in the colon to show up. Otherwise it would show up as is.

Comment: thanks,it is the file that i have not created.@Ulto4